# grayscale - how to disable it automatically

Tags: html, css, filter, grayscale

Many websites in Thailand are now in grayscale, mostly using -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%), filter: grayscale(100%) and so on.

I know we can see them in colors as usual, "manually" (in Chrome) by pressing/clicking the F12 > elements > styles and uncheck grayscale filter check-boxes. But this is not a good way if we need to do the procedure on every webpage.

So, I tried extensions like CustomBlocker, stylish, stylebot, etc,... with no success. They can css-select but cannot correctly edit/inject/insert/remove on the grayscale filters.

I have tried most thing found in google for almost 4 hours with little results. Please help me:

How to automatically disable the grayscale filters on any webpages which are using them ?

Thank you very much for your helpful insights in advance.

p.s.  you may try on a website like http://www.bangkokpost.com/

Comment: Do you have another website to try? Disabling JavaScript works for this link. But the filter should work for CSS filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it appears you have already tried this you should create a custom CSS stylesheet that Chrome will use with a plugin like [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) (not sure if there is a built in feature in Chrome).

Then you override the `filter` in the custom stylesheet.

```
* {
    -webkit-filter: none !important; 
    filter: none !important; 
}
```

However with the site that you referenced, the whole site is being greyscaled via JavaScript, so in this case all I could do was disable JavaScript in my browser. This makes everything colourful again.

Comment: I modified your code a bit and now it's working great. I just realize the real power of the Stylish extension. Thanks a lot for your help.  And here's the modified one:

Comment: html {
    -webkit-filter: none !important;
    filter: none !important;
}

body.grayscale {
    -webkit-filter: none !important; 
    filter: none !important; 
}

Comment: html {
    -webkit-filter: none !important;
    filter: none !important;
}

body.grayscale {
    -webkit-filter: none !important; 
    filter: none !important; 
}

Comment: (sorry for the double post and wrong format.. i'm new here.)

Comment: `*` targets every element on the page.

Comment: great and best answer - short, simple, working on all Thai websites I tried so far.